# How to insert an item to first index of a filled List in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, list

I ve a list which is filled by me and sorted! I wanna add some new items to that sorted list but these new items should be at the top of the list.

**I'm adding items to list:**

```
var OnlySup = dataContext.GroupDetails.Where(c => c.sup_id == c.suppliers.supplier_id).Select(c=>c.sup_id).Distinct().ToList();

/* GET SUPPLIERS FROM DB */
foreach (var supp in OnlySup)
{
    /* ADD EACH SUPPLIER TO LIST */
    SupplierList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = supp.supplier, Value = "S" + supp.supplier_id.ToString() });
}
```

**Sorting:**

```
/* ReOrder The List */
SupplierList = SupplierList.OrderBy(c => c.Text).ToList();
```

**List items that i wanna add to the top of the list:**

```
/* DEFAULT ADD */
SupplierList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "ALL Groups", Value = "G" });
SupplierList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "ALL Suppliers", Value = "S" });
SupplierList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "ALL Suppliers AND Groups", Value = "%" });

/* GET GROUPS FROM DB */
var OnlyGroup = dataContext.groups.OrderBy(c => c.id).Distinct().ToList();

/* FOR EACH GROUP */
foreach (var groups in OnlyGroup)
{
    /* ADD EACH GROUP TO LIST */
    SupplierList.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = groups.group_name, Value = "G" + groups.id.ToString() });
}
```

So how can i achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you invoke the Insert method ?

Comment: wauw it only took a couple minutes to 3 answers congratz to all! 
and ty for reminding..

Answer (score 1):

Create a new list and add the items you want at the start, then add the other items that you sorted earlier. Sould do work if I didn't misunderstand you completely.

```
NewList.Add(the new ones)

foreach(var item in SupplierList){
NewList.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: u understand me well and ur method is worthy but this would be a longer way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that came to my mind, would be to prepare a list with all these items.
So you can use `MyList.Insert(0)` for your new Items.
then I will generate the select list with something similar to this:

```
var select = new SelectLis(MyList, "Id", "Text", Model.SelectedValueId)
```

Comment: why do you regenerate the list anyway after using insert?

Comment: Because I was wrong in reading your code. I was assuming you were trying to update the already compiled SelectList. So the first thing was to create the list from IList so you can call "Insert". After that you generate the selectlist from the list with all your items in the correct order